# JNDI for Local interface EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi

I would like to know if it is meaningfull ang therefore allowed/applicable to access a `Session EJB` with only a `Local` interface view through `JNDI`.

If I am not mistaken, if the client runs in the same application in which the `Bean` to be accessed is deployed, subsequently in `Java EE` environment, then the preferable way is `Dependency Injection`. If the client runs on a different application, then the Local interface view is not visible/accessible. I come to the conclusion then that JNDI access applies virtually only to `Remote` view interface EJBs. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, you could use the Local interface as long as your client is running in the same virtual machine, regarding your cuestion, not really, there are some cases in which you'd like to look up your local interface instead of injecting it (e.g. from a non-managed client component), and besides, under the hood, an injection is nothing but a jndi look up.